# Spring Boot JPA : using criteria without persistence.xml

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I'm new to Spring Boot and JPA I followed tutorials and all was going well until I tried to use Criteria (to build complex dynamic query).

first off all, this is pom.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <parent>
  <groupId>com.scalian.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>atelier</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 
 <artifactId>ServerModule</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency> 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>



 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/resources/</outputDirectory>
       <resources>
        <resource>
         <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/ClientModule/src/main/web/dist/clientapplication/</directory>
        </resource>
       </resources>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
  
</project>
```

this is my main app class :

```js
package com.scalian.app.atelier;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.scalian.app.atelier.persistence.repositories.EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AtelierApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
 
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
  SpringApplication.run(AtelierApplication.class, args);
 }

 @Override
 public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

  EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder environmentCriteriaBuilder = new EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder(); //Error when adding this line :(
  
 }
 
}
```

this is the EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder class :

```js
package com.scalian.app.atelier.persistence.repositories;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder {
  
 public EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder() {
  
  EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("atelierPersistenceUnit").createEntityManager();
  entityManager.close();
 }
 
}
```

and this is the configuration class I made :

```js
package com.scalian.app.atelier;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.scalian.app.atelier.persistence.repositories", entityManagerFactoryRef = "atelierEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef = "atelierTransactionManager")
public class AtelierConfig {
 
 @Bean
 @Primary
 public DataSource firstDataSource() {
  DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
     dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atelier");
     dataSource.setUsername( "username" );
     dataSource.setPassword( "userpassword" );
     return dataSource;
 }


 @Bean
 public DataSource secondDataSource() {
  return null;
 }
 
 @Bean(name="atelierEntityManagerFactory")
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
  
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(firstDataSource()); 
      em.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      em.setPackagesToScan("com.scalian.app.atelier.persistence.entities");
      em.setPersistenceUnitName("atelierPersistenceUnit");
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
      em.setLoadTimeWeaver(new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver());
 
      return em;
   }

  @Bean(name="atelierTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
   JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
   transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
   return transactionManager;
  }
  
  @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

  
  
 Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class, hbm");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
         
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Finaly here's the console output :

> ... 2018-10-05 10:51:25.045  INFO 6972 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   8080 (http) with context path '' 2018-10-05 10:51:25.049  INFO 6972
>   --- [  restartedMain] c.s.app.atelier.AtelierApplication       : Started AtelierApplication in 8.022 seconds (JVM running for 8.589)
>   2018-10-05 10:51:25.059  INFO 6972 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.h.j.b.internal.PersistenceXmlParser    : HHH000318: Could not find
>   any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
>
> ... Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence
>   provider for EntityManager named atelierPersistenceUnit ...
>
> 2018-10-05 10:51:25.069  INFO 6972 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@44840690:
>   startup date [Fri Oct 05 10:51:17 CEST 2018]; root of context
>   hierarchy 2018-10-05 10:51:25.072  INFO 6972 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans on shutdown 2018-10-05 10:51:25.075  INFO 6972 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'atelierPersistenceUnit'

I can't see what is doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a ne EntityManagerFactory and a new EntityManager instead of using the one that you have configured as a Spring bean? Inject the EntityManager, using the `@PersistenceContext annotation`. But of course EnvironmentCriteriaBuilder will have to be a Spring bean, too. You shouldn't use nw to create it.

Comment: If all this comes from a single tutorial: stop using that tutorial.

Comment: Just my opinion .... since u already have `@EnableJpaRepositories` , why not use that(JpaRepositoies) to make your queries. It uses native query as well so its a better choice and easy t implement